# Datatables Jquery expand / collapse by clicking TR

Tags: jquery, css, datatables, tablerow

I am using the jquery datatables plugin and i'd like to have my table expand by clicking TR.

There is an example on their website, which expands and collapses by clicking an image in a column:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/row_details.html

Please can someone help me modify the code below, so that I can expand / collapse the row by clicking TR

```
/* Formating function for row details */
        function fnFormatDetails ( oTable, nTr )
        {
            var aData = oTable.fnGetData( nTr );
            var sOut = '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">';
            sOut += '<tr><td>Rendering engine:</td><td>'+aData[1]+' '+aData[4]+'</td></tr>';
            sOut += '<tr><td>Link to source:</td><td>Could provide a link here</td></tr>';
            sOut += '<tr><td>Extra info:</td><td>And any further details here (images etc)</td></tr>';
            sOut += '</table>';

            return sOut;
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            /*
             * Insert a 'details' column to the table
             */
            var nCloneTh = document.createElement( 'th' );
            var nCloneTd = document.createElement( 'td' );
            nCloneTd.innerHTML = '<img src="../examples_support/details_open.png">';
            nCloneTd.className = "center";

            $('#example thead tr').each( function () {
                this.insertBefore( nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0] );
            } );

            $('#example tbody tr').each( function () {
                this.insertBefore(  nCloneTd.cloneNode( true ), this.childNodes[0] );
            } );

            /*
             * Initialse DataTables, with no sorting on the 'details' column
             */
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
                ],
                "aaSorting": [[1, 'asc']]
            });

            /* Add event listener for opening and closing details
             * Note that the indicator for showing which row is open is not controlled by DataTables,
             * rather it is done here
             */
            $('#example tbody td img').live('click', function () {
                var nTr = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                if ( this.src.match('details_close') )
                {
                    /* This row is already open - close it */
                    this.src = "../examples_support/details_open.png";
                    oTable.fnClose( nTr );
                }
                else
                {
                    /* Open this row */
                    this.src = "../examples_support/details_close.png";
                    oTable.fnOpen( nTr, fnFormatDetails(oTable, nTr), 'details' );
                }
            } );
        } );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in there, then write a function to do the expand/collapse event.

```
$('#example tbody tr').click( function () {

       $('#example tbody tr').myExpandCollapseFunction();

}
```

Put the code right after this code ...

```
    $('#example thead tr').each( function () {
        this.insertBefore( nCloneTh, this.childNodes[0] );
    } );

    $('#example tbody tr').each( function () {
        this.insertBefore(  nCloneTd.cloneNode( true ), this.childNodes[0] );
    } );
```

Comment: using "live" is better than "click" as it won't bind the event. It becomes significant on a large table.